# How to add an extra label to 1000s of prometheus queries in grafana dashboard programmatically?

Tags: python, prometheus, grafana

I have almost 1000 prometheus queries configured in my grafana dashboard, and I need to add one more label to all the queries to get the correct metric, since this label was added recently to differentiate the metrics based on region. I know what the query is, but adding the new label manually in all 1000 queries seems a tedious and repetitive work. Is there a way to programmatically add a label to an existing query string (by using some parsing library in any programming language or regex pattern of queries)?

For eg, if I have a query:

`sum(increase(django_http_responses_total_by_status_view_method_total{view="some_api_function", status="200"}[5m]))`

I need to add one more label to it:

`sum(increase(django_http_responses_total_by_status_view_method_total{view="some_api_function", status="200", region="us-east-1"}[5m]))`

Adding it manually for lesser number of queries is not an issue, but for 1000s of such queries, it becomes difficult. I was even able to parse the grafana dashboard json and get all the queries in it using this snippet:

```
import json

with open("grafana-dashboad.json", "r") as f:
    dashboard_data = json.load(f)

panels = dashboard_data["panels"]

queries = []

for panel in panels:
    title = panel.get("title")
    # print(f"Title: {title}")
    targets = panel.get("targets", [])
    for target in targets:
        query = target["expr"]
        queries.append(query)
    inner_panels = panel.get("panels", [])
    for inner_panel in inner_panels:
        inner_targets = inner_panel.get("targets", [])
        for inner_target in inner_targets:
            query = inner_target["expr"]
            queries.append(query)
for query in queries:
    print(query)
print(len(queries))
```

But I am not sure how to proceed further to add the extra label in the query programmatically. Is there any best way or library to get this done automated, rather than updating the queries manually one-by-one? Can the metric somehow be parsed into a python object, so that the label can be updated? If not python, I am also fine with using any other language, as long as it makes the work easier.

Comment: You have two problems and you've addressed the first (parsing the JSON config) but not the second (parsing the PromQL expression and correctly adding the new label. There's a "correct" way to do this which would be to parse the `expr` into syntax trees and then there's a "quick and dirty" way to do the entire thing. Even if you parse into syntax trees, you'll need to be careful that you're correctly adding the labels and, if adding the labels is sufficiently easy, I think the "quick and dirty" approach will be as effective.

Comment: So, my quick-and-dirty suggestion is to use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html). This assumes that you can add `region="us-east-1"` to **every** occurrence of a metric and every occurrence of a metric includes at least zero labels `{}`. This command does not update|replace `grafana-dashboard.json` just produces a variant of it with the new label: `sed --express="s|{\(.*\)}|{\1,region=\\\\\"us-east-1\\\\\"}|g" grafana-dashboard.json`. You can pipe the result through `grep` to filter the result by `expr` to prove that it works `| grep expr`.

Comment: Explanation: `{\(.*\)}` escape a regex that matches everything between `{X}` and then replaces that with `{X, region=\"us-east-1\"}`.

Comment: @DazWilkin Thanks for your suggestion, but I was able to get it done using this python library: https://github.com/pabluk/pygments-promql

Comment: That's a very interesting module. Glad you got it working (the "correct" way ;-))

Comment: An alternative solution is to use VictoriaMetrics instead of Prometheuss and specify `extra_label` query arg in Prometheus datasource config. In this case VictoriaMetrics would automatically add the given extra label to all the queries sent from this datasource. See https://docs.victoriametrics.com/#prometheus-querying-api-enhancements for details

Comment: @valyala We are using VictoriaMetrics, and the extra label is already added in the metrics. But in places like Grafana and AlertManager, the queries need to be updated with the extra label, thats where I was looking for a programmatic way

Answer (score 1):

I was able to parse the promql query string as python objects, and add my own label to it using this python library: https://github.com/pabluk/pygments-promql

```
from pygments import highlight, lex, format
from pygments.formatters import NullFormatter
from pygments.token import Name, Operator, Literal, Punctuation
from pygments_promql import PromQLLexer

query = 'sum(increase(django_http_responses_total_by_status_view_method_total{view="some_api_function", status="200"}[5m]))'
# print(highlight(query, PromQLLexer(), NullFormatter()))
promql_lex = list(lex(query, PromQLLexer()))

label_start_index = None
for index, token in enumerate(promql_lex):
    if list(token)[0] == Name.Label and list(token)[1] == "view":
        # print("First label", token, type(list(token)[0]))
        label_start_index = index
        break
print(format(lex(query, PromQLLexer()), NullFormatter()))

new_label = [(Name.Label, "region"), (Operator, '='), (Punctuation, '"'), (Literal.String, "us-east-1"), (Punctuation, '"'), (Punctuation, ',')]
# print(format(new_label, NullFormatter()))
# print(label_start_index)
promql_lex[label_start_index:label_start_index] = new_label
# print(promql_lex)
print(format(promql_lex, NullFormatter()))
```

I have made this code as a function, and used it in the grafana dashboard parsing snippet that I added in my question to update all the queries in the dashboard json file.